# How do I change the color of my hostname in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

```
$john@server-dev2:~/myproject/src/production
```

I would like to change "server-dev2" to yellow.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your bash_profile or .profile modify the colors when you define PS1

For example:

```
export PS1='\[\e[1;31m\][\D{%a %m-%d-%Y %T} \u@\h \W]\$\[\e[0m\] '
```

Gives you

```
[Mon 09-01-2014 22:59:09 user@hostname path]#
```

In red.

You can refer to the [Bash Prompt Escape Sequences](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html) and [Bash Prompt HOWTO:](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

`export PS1='\u@\[\e[1;33m\]\h\[\e[0m\]:\w\$ '`

The PS1 variable controls what the shell displays in its prompt.  To cause the host name in your prompt to appear in a yellow foreground color the escape sequence for the host, indicated by \h above, must be surrounded by the escape codes that start and stop a color sequence.  The code for yellow is \e[1;33m.  The color sequences are bounded by the escape codes \[ and \] to indicate to the shell they are non-printing codes that should not take up any space in the prompt.

Comment: Could you please include some explanation in your answer?